# How to make two parallel requests with different error types using sequenceT and ReaderTaskEither?

Tags: fp-ts

I want to make two parallel requests using `sequenceT` function and work with results, but it shows me an error which I cannot resolve on my own

```js
import * as RTE from 'fp-ts/ReaderTaskEither'
import * as Ap from 'fp-ts/Apply'

Ap.sequenceT(RTE.ApplyPar)(
  getUserById('1'),
  getSpecialistById('2')
) // <- This method shows error
```

Error

```
Type 'SpecialistNotFoundError' is not assignable to type 'UserNotFoundError'.
          Types of property 'code' are incompatible.
            Type '"SPECIALIST_NOT_FOUND"' is not assignable to type '"USER_NOT_FOUND"'
```

Code that may help to understand the problem

```js
function getSpecialistById (specialistId: string): RTE.ReaderTaskEither<PrismaClient, SpecialistNotFoundError, Specialist> {
  return (prisma: PrismaClient) => {
    return TE.tryCatch(
      () => prisma.specialist.findUnique({ where: { id: specialistId }, rejectOnNotFound: true }),
      () => new SpecialistNotFoundError()
    )
  }
}

function getUserById (userId: string): RTE.ReaderTaskEither<PrismaClient, UserNotFoundError, User> {
  return (prisma: PrismaClient) => {
    return TE.tryCatch(
      () => prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: userId }, rejectOnNotFound: true }),
      () => new UserNotFoundError()
    )
  }
}

class UserNotFoundError extends Error {
  readonly code = 'USER_NOT_FOUND'

  constructor () {
    super('User not found')
  }
}

class SpecialistNotFoundError extends Error {
  readonly code = 'SPECIALIST_NOT_FOUND'

  constructor () {
    super('Specialist not found')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rather than using `sequenceT` (as I don't think it's capable of handling the types correctly for what you're trying to do) I would instead use `Do` notation like follows:

```js
const result = pipe(
  RTE.Do,
  RTE.apS("user", getUserById("1")),
  RTE.apSW("spec", getSpecialistById("2")),
  RTE.map(({ user, spec }) => {
    return `${user.id}:${spec.id}`;
  })
);
```

`result` will be `RTE.ReadTaskEither<PrismaClient, UserNotFoundError | SpecialistNotFoundError, string>` in this case since I returned a `string` in `map`.

Here are [the docs on `Do` notation](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/do-notation.html#examples). Note at the bottom where it shows how to do things in parallel

Comment: Yes, it works! Btw, is there any rule of thumb when to use `Do` notation vs simple `pipe`/`flow`? Or `Do` notation is preferable approach of writing fp apps?

Comment: I think `Do` notation is just sort of the newer way of writing stuff (it's a relatively new API). In my opinion it seems to be a bit friendlier to work with. I think that `pipe`/`flow` are going to be in your toolbox no matter what but `Do` notation is good for when you're working with multiple Monads at once and you want to combine them all together. It often comes up when you have multiple `Eithers` specifically because it can handle this case nicer than `Sequence`

Comment: The problem with `sequenceT` in the snippet shared is that the error types of these `ReaderTaskEither` are different and `sequenceT` requires them to be the same. The problem with the `Do` notation and `apS` is that only a single error can be propagated even though multiple errors could have occurred. In https://stackoverflow.com/a/72600492/4874344 I shared an idea how we may use `sequenceT` to unwrap multiple results and multiple errors in a type-safe way.